# Show/Hide divs not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, togglebutton

I need some buttons which on click shows the related `div`s and hide the rest.

I googled the below code. It is working as expected on jsfiddle.net, but it's not on my server. I get something like this, and of course the 'buttons' aren't working as well:

```
button1 button2 button3 button4 button5
part1
part2
part3
part4
part5
```

Code:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.showSingle').on('click', function () {
    $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
    $('.targetDiv').hide();
    $('#div' + $(this).data('target')).show();
});
$('.showSingle').first().click();
</script>

<div class="buttons">
    <a  class="showSingle" data-target="1">button1</a>
    <a  class="showSingle" data-target="2">button2</a>
    <a  class="showSingle" data-target="3">button3</a>
    <a  class="showSingle" data-target="4">button4</a>
    <a  class="showSingle" data-target="5">button5</a>
</div>

<div id="div1" class="targetDiv">part1</div>
<div id="div2" class="targetDiv">part2</div>
<div id="div3" class="targetDiv">part3</div>
<div id="div4" class="targetDiv">part4</div>
<div id="div5" class="targetDiv">part5</div>
```

Comment: I would suggest you to use "mixitup" jQuery plugin. Take a look at this example http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-For-Filtering-Sorting-Html-Elements-MixItUp/ OR https://mixitup.kunkalabs.com/

Comment: Code as-is works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/17psur23/ provided you're executing it in the proper order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following at the beginning of your script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   //Your logic
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need either place your jQuery at the end of the page, or wrap it in a [document.ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) call (e.g. `$( document ).ready(function() {...`).

You're attempting to execute code on elements that don't yet exist. jsFiddle defaults to a window.onload which is why it works there.

Comment: It is still the same.

Comment: What errors are you getting in the browser console?

Comment: Do you have a link we can see?

Answer (score 1):

you need to place your jquery code inside a document ready block. this would look like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.showSingle').on('click', function () {
    $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
    $('.targetDiv').hide();
    $('#div' + $(this).data('target')).show();
   });
   $('.showSingle').first().click();
});
</script>
```

This block basically tells jquery to only execute the encompassed code once the DOM has been loaded, this is required as your code is manipulating DOM element.

Comment: It is still the same.

Comment: strange, what server are you using to serve your html?

Comment: Actually it's a content editor web part on a SharePoint 2010 site. I use dozens of js/html scripts the same way and all of them work OK.

Comment: hmmm, well this is the complete example which works when i run from within my webserver : http://pastebin.com/9Q6ZbJz6

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the script in your local system, add the "https:" or "http:" protocol in the external script URL.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

> Your jQuery methods inside a document ready event:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) {
 $('.showSingle').on('click', function () {
  $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
   $('.targetDiv').hide();
   $('#div' + $(this).data('target')).show();
});
   $('.showSingle').first().click();
});
</script>
```